# How can I efficiently compare a list of objects' fields and display in JSF

Tags: algorithm, optimization, comparison, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I have a list of quite detailed objects to compare:

```
List<MyObject> objectsToCompare;
```

In the objects there are many fields which could be another Object, String, int, list, etc.

I need to present to the user a table representation of these objects and their fields using JSF like this:

```
field    object1     object2    object3...  equal
name     fred        john       george...   no
age      26          26         26...       yes
```

Here's what I have planned so far for my JSF page:

```
<p:panelGrid >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>Field</p:column>
                <ui:repeat var="loopObject" value="#{compareObjectsBean.objectsForComparison}">
                    <p:column><h:outputText value="#{loopObject.id}" /></p:column>
                </ui:repeat>
                <p:column>All Objects Equal</p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>Name</p:column>
                <ui:repeat var="loopObject" value="#{compareObjectsBean.objectsForComparison}">
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{loopObject.name}" /></p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:column><h:outputText value="#{compareObjectsController.namesEqual()?'yes':'no'}"/> </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column>Age</p:column>
                <ui:repeat var="loopObject" value="#{compareObjectsBean.objectsForComparison}">
                <p:column><h:outputText value="#{loopObject.age}" /></p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:column><h:outputText value="#{compareObjectsController.agesEqual()?'yes':'no'}"/> </p:column>
        </p:row>
```

and for example in the compareObjectsController is a comparison method for each field:

```
public boolean namesEqual(){
        String firstObjectName = compareObjectsBean.getObjectsForComparison().get(0).getName();
        for(int i = 1; i< compareObjectsBean.getObjectsForComparison().size(); i++){
            if(!compareObjectsBean.getObjectsForComparison().get(i).getName().equals(firstObjectName)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;//all matched the first, so all are equal
    }
```

This doesn't seem very efficient, especially when the objects being compared have approx 300 fields (includes fields of objects belonging to MyObject).

**How can I optimise/optimize this so that I do not need to write ~300 comparison methods in the controller, and possibly also ~300 rows?**

Note: I am also using primefaces, but this could just be a simple table.

Comment: With that amount of fields you could maybe use reflection

Comment: In the end I did use reflection.

Comment: Reflection is fun :-)